# Is there any probability distance that preserves all properties of a metric?

Tags: distributions, distance, metric

In studying Kullback–Leibler distance, there are two things we learn very quickly is that it does not respect neither the triangle inequality nor the symmetry, required properties of a metric.

My question is whether there is any metric of probability density functions that fulfil [all the constraints of a metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29#Definition).

Comment: To focus on probability *densities* is to focus on the "wrong" object. As for metrics, there are the "classical" ones, e.g., [Lévy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levy_metric) (and the related Ky Fan metric on random variables), Wasserstein along with ones closer in spirit to KL, e.g., [Jensen-Shannon divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence). Though mostly overlooked historically, note that in [the original KL paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177729694), the *KL divergence* was indeed symmetric (though still not a metric).

Comment: @cardinal, well, I'm not so much in the field, can you please suggest the "right" object?

Comment: J.C.: Sorry, the comment box became too small for all I was trying to fit in there. I should have elaborated. The cumulative distribution function turns out to be a more general and natural object of study. :-)

Comment: @cardinal [why?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86983/why-it-is-better-to-use-the-cumulative-distribution-to-compute-distances) ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Take a look at [this paper that covers a wide range of popular metrics on the space of probability measure](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0209021.pdf). My personal favorites are the total variation distance and $L^2$ Wasserstein distance (earth mover distance).

Comment: That is a good paper - especially figure 1. I'm saving a copy of that for future reference.

Comment: @Ramanujan updated to an arxiv link.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that the [Earth Mover's Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Mover%27s_Distance), also known as the [Wasserstein metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric), is an example which meets your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There are some modifications to the KL divergence that make it acquire some of the metric properties (though not all).

For example, the [Jeffrey’s divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_(statistics)#f-divergences) modifies the KL divergence to make it symmetric.

There are some special cases see [1]: 
"Unfortunately, traditional measures based on the Kullback–Leibler (KL) divergence and the Bhattacharyya distance do not satisfy all metric axioms necessary for many algorithms. In this paper we propose a modification for the KL divergence and the Bhattacharyya distance, for multivariate Gaussian densities, that transforms the two measures into distance metrics."

[1] K. Abou-Moustafa and F. Ferrie, "A Note on Metric Properties for Some Divergence Measures: The Gaussian Case," JMLR: Workshop and Conference Proceedings 25:1–15, 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I think that answer to the question is possible. Because, recently in 2017 R. Farhadian showed that there is a probability on a heuristic sub set of integers that it is a metric. for his work, see the following link: http://journals.univ-danubius.ro/index.php/oeconomica/article/view/4010